# Is adding a column and a constraint at the same time while modifying an Oracle table possible?

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints, alter-table

I have an assignment asking me to add a column to a table and give it a constraint.

> "Add a column named Base_Salary with a datatype of NUMBER(7,2) to the
>   store_reps table. Ensure that the amount entered is above 0."

I thought it was pretty straight forward, but maybe I have to ALTER the table twice, once for the new column, and again for adding the constraints? That seems redundant and inefficient.

I've tried taking off the second 'ADD' and moving around the parentheses, and moving the commas, it seems there is a similar error for everything I do.

This is my attempt:

```
ALTER TABLE store_reps; 
 ADD (Base_Salary NUMBER(7, 2)),
 ADD CONSTRAINT store_reps_Base_Salary CHECK (Base_Salary>0);
```

I get an error

```
ADD CONSTRAINT store_reps_Base_Salary CHECK (Base_Salary>0)
ERROR report - 
UNKNOWN COMMAND
```

and another:

```
Error starting at line : 74 in command -
ALTER TABLE store_reps 
 ADD (Base_Salary NUMBER(7, 2)),
 CONSTRAINT store_reps_Base_Salary CHECK (Base_Salary>0)
Error report -
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I just started SQL a few weeks ago, and am very much noob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query contains two syntax problems that need to be fixed:

- get rid of the comma before `CONSTRAINT`
- get rid of the extra pair of braces around `Base_Salary NUMBER(7, 2)`

Working example:

```
create table store_reps (id number);

ALTER TABLE store_reps 
 ADD Base_Salary NUMBER(7, 2)
 CONSTRAINT store_reps_Base_Salary CHECK (Base_Salary>0);
```

Comment: Thank you, that was very informative. I'm glad you could easily pick out my syntax mistakes. This seemed to work for me: 

  ADD (Base_Salary NUMBER(7, 2)
     CONSTRAINT store_reps_Base_Salary CHECK (Base_Salary>0));

Even though it functions as I expect, is it still improper syntax?

Comment: Should be fine - it's just a matter of personal preference IMHO.

Comment: Please note that CHECK constraints accept NULL values. Your column BASE_SALARY could contain NULLs. If you don't want NULLs, you need to include a NOT NULL constraint.

Answer (score 1):

```
create table tr (col1 number);

alter table tr add col2 varchar2(100) constraint tr_cons CHECK (col2 = 'a');
```

[DB Fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2adaca052f0e3cfe1aefa15a74f10053)

Cheers!!